# Tensorflow: bag of words text classification: Cannot feed value of shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-classification

I've nicked this code here: https://sourcedexter.com/tensorflow-text-classification-python/ to try to predict if a given question is either one of two categories.

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1666) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Relevant code below:

```
# train_x contains the Bag of words and train_y contains the label/ category
train_x = list(training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])

#reset underlying graph data
tf.reset_default_graph()
#Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None,len(train_x[0])])
#layer?
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net,8)
#layer?
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net,8)
#output layer
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]),activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)


#define model and set up tensorboard
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir = 'tflearn_logs')
#start training (grad descent algo)
model.fit(train_x, train_x, n_epoch = 1000, batch_size=1, show_metric = True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is common shape mismatch error
- Error is self-explanatory
- Your target tensor is of shape [None, 2]
- You are feeding you target tensor an array of (1, 1666)
- Your **model.fit()** should be:

  `model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)`
- See the second parameter which is the target `train_y` but you have given the second parameter as `train_x`
- which means you are saying that your inputs are you labels which is not true
- May be that's why its throwing you the error

Comment: Geez louise, yes that's fixed it. Thank you and sorry for being lazy in checking my code